# Error AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'", 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python, lambda, apply, isnull

I am trying to run an apply lambda function on an object column. How can I check that row 3 below is a Nan value

Example test scores:

```
100,10,Nan,50,10,Nan
```

```
def add_grade(row):
    if row[test_scores].isnull():
       return 'F'
    else:
       return 'Passing'
```

when I run the above I get this error: "AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isnull'", 'occurred at index 0')
"

Comment: `isnull()` is a pandas method. `row` is not a pandas dataframe.